# laravel 5.2 create common function for controllers? must use helper?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want to create a functions which can be called by all controllers

```
public function getSuffix($filename) {

    $first_char = substr($filename, 0 ,1);
    $sec_char = substr($filename, 1 ,1);
    $suffix ="";

    if($first_char!='.' && $first_char!='..')
        $suffix .= '/'.$first_char.'/';
    if($sec_char!='.' && $sec_char!='..')
        $suffix .= $sec_char.'/';

    return $suffix;
}
```

what is the best practice for doing this? Is helper class what i'm searching?

Answer (score 7):

create a helpers.php file inside app/http folder. then your composer.json file autoload this file .

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

then run composer dump-autoload your problem is solved

Answer (score 3):

First you need to create folder in app like CustomFolder and create you helper class in custom folder like SimpleClass.php

```
<?php
namespace App\CustomFolder;
class SimpleClass {

public function yourFunction(){
   return true;
} 

}

?>
```

when you use this helper class in your controller simple add namespace like

```
<?php

use App\CustomFolder\SimpleClass;
class MyController extends Controller{

}

?>
```

I think your helper class work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Create Base class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //do some stuff
    }

    public function myFunction()
    {

    }
}
```

And extend all your classes with this base class.